# Reading specific lines in a .Log file

Tags: c#

I have a log file that I am reading into different objects. One object starts at a Line that contains the words "Announce message" and the following lines contain the data that belongs to that message. This entry stops at a line that contains the word "Disposed".
I want to read all the data from between these 2 lines that, contains certain words.

Im currently using a Dictionary because the line with "Announce message" also contains a UID but the following lines contain the data for that UID.

How would you do that?

This is what i have come up with so far.

```
public static void P2PLogParser(List<FileInfo> fileList)
{
    foreach (FileInfo fi in fileList)
    {
        //Læser alle linier i csv fil
        foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(fi.FullName))
        {
            string MeterUID = GetMeterUID(line);
            string MimHashcode = GetMimHashcode(line);
            string FirmwareUploadStatus = GetFirmwareUploadStatus(line);
            string IsKnown = GetIsKnown(line);
            DateTime P2PTimeStamp = GetTimestamp(line);
            if (IsMeterEntry(line) && !meters.ContainsKey(MeterUID))
            {
                string MeterNr = GetMeterUID(line).Replace("4B414D", "");
                int meternr = int.Parse(MeterNr, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                meters.Add(MeterUID, new Meter()
                {
                    MeterUID = MeterUID,
                    MeterNR = meternr,
                    P2Pmeterentry = new List<P2PMeterEntry>()
                });
            }
            if (IsMeterEntry(line))
            {
                P2PMeterEntry p2pmeter = new P2PMeterEntry
                {
                    P2PTimeStamp = P2PTimeStamp,
                    MimHashcode = MimHashcode,
                    FirmwareUploadStatus = FirmwareUploadStatus,
                    IsKnown = IsKnown,
                    P2PMetersession = new List<P2PMeterSession>()
                };
                if (IsNoLongerMeterEntry(line))
                {
                    string SessionLevel = GetLevel(line);
                    string SessionMessage = GetSessionMessage(line);
                    string Context = GetSessionContext(line);
                    P2PMeterSession MeterSession = new P2PMeterSession
                    {
                        SessionTimeStamp = P2PTimeStamp,
                        SessionLevel = SessionLevel,
                        SessionMessage = SessionMessage,
                        Context = Context

                    };
                    meterSession.Add(MeterSession);
                }
                meters[MeterUID].P2Pmeterentry.Add(p2pmeter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the IsMeterEntry and IsNoLongerMeterEntry

```
//IsMeterSession
public static bool IsMeterEntry(string text)
{
    return text.ToLower().Contains("announce message received:");
}

public static bool IsNoLongerMeterEntry(string text)
{
    return text.ToLower().Contains("context - disposed");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement a simple state machine with two states: IgnoreLine (initial state) and Announce.

```
for each line in log
   if line contains "Announce message"
     read UID
     create a StringBuilder
     set state=Announce
   else if line contains "Disposed"
     store the StringBuilder's content in the dictionary[uid]
     set state=IgnoreLine
   else if state==Announce and line contains "certain words"
     append line to StringBuilder
```

Comment: How would you apply the state machine to my code ? sorry im a noob :P

Comment: All you need to do, is to introduce the `state` variable, enum or integer. Also you'll have to replace the `StringBuilder` with you logic. I used `StringBuilder` because I was referring to the original question, which only mentioned reading all data between 2 lines. You have added the code samples later.